# Redirect incoming referral link from Youtube

Tags: .htaccess

A user from a YouTube video has linked to my WordPress home page.
However, i want the incoming traffic to go to another page

I tried with .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v\=xxxxxxxxxx [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/abc/post/ [R=302,L]
```

I am 100% that code is correct, yet it does not work. Are there any other alternatives besides the above code? Perhaps with PHP that I can use in the header or index file?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, youtube links are usually https so you should add a check for that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} https?\://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v\=xxxxxxxxxx [NC]
```

The other thing is you need a space before the end of the video and the `[NC]` flag.